# Is that Dragon's cargo exposed to space environment in this picture?

Tags: spacex, dragon

The lower section of Dragon, holding the solar panels, are ditched during descent.

So, is Dragon carrying cargo in that section during ascent?

[image]

Source of the image: [Launch & Spacecraft Visit to Space Station - SpaceX](https://vimeo.com/41871982)

Comment: I've also found the answer on this [related question](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/how-is-unpressurized-cargo-useful-at-the-iss)

Comment: Can you please [edit] to include the source and credit for the image you attach? It's a frame from SpaceX Dragon promo video: [Launch & Spacecraft Visit to Space Station (Animation)](https://vimeo.com/41871982). Thanks!

Comment: This sounds *just like* a Skeptics.SE question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that section is usually called *trunk* and it may contain *unpressurized cargo* - up to 14 m<sup>3</sup> (compared to 10 m<sup>3</sup> of pressurized payload) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(spacecraft)))

You can see it being loaded with [BEAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigelow_Expandable_Activity_Module) [image: BEAM being loaded to Dragon trunk for CRS-8]

([Twitter post](https://twitter.com/BigelowSpace/status/694714898123661312))

And here is what seems like a real photo of the open section from the ISS [image: Inspection of Dragon aft by remote cameras]

([nasaspaceflight.com article](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2013/03/ssrms-removes-payload-dragon-trunk-new-milestone/))

Comment: So the obvious question that follows is.... how does it not fall out? Is simply tying things down enough to keep it in place after a violent rocket launch and stage separation?

Comment: It is probably fastened really tightly, otherwise it could damage the top of the second stage after liftoff which would very probably lead to a RUD. If it was kept in place during the launch then it should not get loose just because it is in free fall in vacuum.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I suppose thats what the metal protrusions are for on the BEAM.